# How to display countdown timer in tableau dashboard?

Tags: countdowntimer, tableau-api

I want to display countdown timer in tableau dashboard.
I have tried different calculation filed formula.
Is there any other way ?

Comment: What do you want a countdown timer for? What should it count down to and how do you want to display it?

Comment: @Alexander i want to display dashboard for limited time so I want to display countdown clock for timeout alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion above is the best Tableau based solution. Another alternative is to create a countdown on one of the many free websites that let you do this, then show it on your dashboard using the 'web page' object.

Comment: Please suggest that websites

Answer (score 2):

Without elaborate tricks you will not be able to show a dynamic countdown.

If you have a fixed target time you can calculate the datediff dynamically and display that with every refresh (you cannot force it to refresh regularly)

```
DATEDIFF('seconds',now(),[TargetDate])
```

You could even hide a dashboard once the targetdate is reached by creating a field

```
DATEDIFF('seconds',now(),[TargetDate]) < 0
```

and filtering the values that are FALSE. Once the traget date is reached, everything will be false and the graph will be empty.

However you will not be able to for example hide a graph 20 seconds after somebody opened your dashboard. At least not with working around a lot of obstacles.

If you have a Tableau Server at hand you could try something like getting the event data from the Tableau Server data base, checking for when the currently logged in user accessed the dashboard the last time and calculating the datediff between that time and now(). This sounds overly complicated though and you will need to have a Server AND access to the Tableau DB.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander your idea is good but tableau not showing continuous change. It's look like static timer however your hide dashboard calculation is very useful.